# Error in houghtransform lines

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, hough-transform

I am trying to get the hough lines using Opencv and Python on a web cam.

But I am getting an error as  Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python27/Hough_video_try.py", line 14, in for rho,theta in lines[0]: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Below is my code, Please help

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True): s, img = cam.read()
  winName = "Movement Indicator"
  cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
  edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
  lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,2,None,30,1)
  if lines is None:
    for rho,theta in lines[0]:

        pt1 = (line[0],line[1])
        pt2 = (line[2],line[3])
        cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 3)


  cv2.imshow('edges',edges)
  cv2.imshow('original',img)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
     break

  cam.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Which line triggers that error?

Comment: use `if not lines is None` , what is the fun of processing an None object ?

Comment: Clearly `lines is None`; indeed, you have explicitly checked `if lines is None`, so you should really know that. Why are you trying to index into `None`?! Did you mean `if lines is not None`?

Comment: It was a silly mistake from my side. I was checking a wrong condition. But now I am getting a peculiar error as

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python27/Hough_video_try.py", line 14, in

for rho,theta in lines[0]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

I used the same code as given above with correct condition. Please help me out with this error

Comment: @Anurag That may be because lines[0] returns more values than 2, so the returned values are not able to fit in only 2 variables, I guess it returns 4 vaues, kindly confirm it by running len(lines[0]) it will give you a count of no. of values returned , then you can use w,x,y,z = lines[0] but no. of variables always depends on the no of return elements by the function call.

Comment: @Anurag use `for line in lines:` in place of `for rho,theta in lines[0]:` and see if the error disappears ?

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in condition you are checking

```
if lines is None:

    for rho,theta in lines[0]:
```

If the `lines` is `None` how you will get `None[0]`?

Please change condition

```
if lines is not None:

    for rho,theta in lines[0]:
```